# WPF NI Graph x axis

Tags: c#, wpf, graph

I use on `WPF NI Graph`.

I wanted to know is there a way to order the `X axis` according to sec. (my X axis is type of `AxisDouble`)

For example, when I put on DataSource array of 40 double, I would expect to see it on the screen from 0 to 4 and not from 0 to 40 as it actually displays.

Other words, the array is calculated by msec and the screen is shown seconds (40 double suppose to shown between 0 to 4).

Answer (score 0):

use 2 X-axis .

One where you plot the data, hide the markings. 
And the second axis gets no plot data but the labels and range settings are set to visible.